# Matrix/Operator identity proof

Tags: matrices, operator-theory, operator-algebras

I am trying to prove a matrix/operator identity but I can't and I was wondering if somebody could help me with it.
The identity is(for two generally non-commuting matrices/operators):
$\frac{1}{A-B}=\frac{1}{A}+\frac{1}{A}B\frac{1}{A}+\frac{1}{A}B\frac{1}{A}B\frac{1}{A}+...$.

In particular, my problem lies in trying to perform a Taylor expanion:
$\frac{1}{A-B}=\frac{1}{A}(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{A}B})$ which gives

$=\frac{1}{A}+\frac{1}{A^2}B+\frac{1}{A^2}B\frac{1}{A}B+\frac{1}{A^2}B\frac{1}{A}B\frac{1}{A}B+...$

I tried doing it like this:
$\frac{1}{A-B}=(\frac{1}{1-B\frac{1}{A}})\frac{1}{A}$ but it still given non-sense.

So, I am guessing that the right form to bring it in is $\frac{1}{A-B}=\frac{1}{A}(\frac{1}{1-B\frac{1}{A}})$ but I don't understand why this is.

Note: Please, don't be too rigorous as I am only an undergraduate physicist.  Also, the expanion is found in scattering problems for weak potentials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake was in the step where you factored out $A^{-1}$ before applying geometric series.  Note that if $X$ and $Y$ are invertible operators, then $(XY)^{-1}=Y^{-1}X^{-1}$.  Hence $(A-B)^{-1}=(A(1-A^{-1}B))^{-1}=(1-A^{-1}B)^{-1}A^{-1}$.  Hence, provided $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(A^{-1}B)^k$ converges, the identity holds.

Opinion/speculation: Using the notation $X^{-1}$ instead of $\frac1X$ when working with noncommuting variables makes it easier to keep things straight.

Comment: I admire your "understatement" : "makes it easier to keep things straight" where some people would have said abruptly: "is compulsory in noncommutative framework (tell it to your lecturer)"

Comment: @JeanMarie: Notation that seems "wrong" to me might well work for another context.  E.g. if for some reason this is standard among some physicists, I will not try to fight it.  What would definitely be objectionable would be using $\dfrac{B}{A}$ when $A$ and $B$ don't (necessarily) commute, which I note is not done here.

Comment: You are right...

Comment: Damn, this answer shows how little I know about operators/matrices. The advice you gave on the last step is truly great! Thanks for answering|!